# Calculate x position value from scaleLinear in d3 returns wrong values

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graph

I am trying to make a line graph in a horizontal scroll with a centered value in the middle of the screen, that updates when a x point hits the line. The issue is the calculated increments are not exact so the centred point ends up being out of line the more you scroll through the graph.

[image]

I am using react-native-svg-graphs & d3-shapes in a horizontal ScrollView.

I have calculated all the values using the width of the screen relative to how many data points you want on the screen at one time and the .length of the data set.

```
const { dataPointsOnScreen } = this.state; 
const width = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width * (DATA.length / dataPointsOnScreen)); 
this.setState({ incrementWidth: width / DATA.length });
```

This was so I could calculate the distance between each increment so I could check to see if the scroll point had past the index * the increment and update the number.

After more research position that is plotted on the X axis is a whole number on the graph, this can be seen by the scroll event, from what I can see I believe there is a way of finding out this exact value from each x point using scaleLinear() but can't quite figure out how to do this as I can't get my head around how d3 calculates the distance of x if x is linear.

Code base here if you want to take a look - https://github.com/eikhunter/horizontal-line-chart-react-native

I've got as far as this

```
    calculateXPosition(index: number): number {
        const { dataPointsOnScreen } = this.state;
        const width = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width * (DATA.length / dataPointsOnScreen));
        const linearScale = scale.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, DATA.length])
            .range([0, width]);

        return linearScale(index);
    }
```

But the value returned still isn't exact to what the middle value is on the graph, it's slightly out

Comment: I think that you should take into account the negative offset on x. If you scrolled to the right then you should use the -x value of the translation to add to the window width when calculating the actual range

Comment: Hey thanks for your input, are you talking about the contentInset I am using on the linechart component? Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Checkout this public gist that I created: https://gist.github.com/cstefanache/ac15942472644b73e6fc10da7cc71812 - I think that the problem you are facing is that you are not taking into consideration the negative scroll and the range is always fixed to the visible are on the same domain. If the index takes into account the scroll then it should be ok.

Comment: So the domain has to take into account how many data points are on the screen at any one time, not sure this is entirely clear. You can set the range implicitly so why does it always remain fixed to the visible area, Is this in the documentation? Still not sure I entirely understand your logic.

Comment: So when calculating the domain value,  I should take into account the current scroll position and take that away from the full width as and when I need it calculated?

Comment: Depends on what you are sending as value for index - is it an x location relative to the scrolled viewport, screen or graph data values?

Comment: Hey, yes, so on scroll I am checking the scroll position then using the above calculation to check whether it has hit the next index x position. here is a gist for it - https://gist.github.com/eikhunter/982a4a56d6f062ec1a12fa3ca3481e3c, where the x location is just calculated with scaleLinear, as the x value is consistent